# Can anyone help identify this uniform?

Tags: identification, uniform

I found this in my great-aunt's pictures after she passed, but no one in my family knows who it might be. We're not even sure it's an American uniform as her side of the family came over from Germany and Ireland. It's a tintype, if that might be relevant.

My cousin [posted it to Twitter](https://twitter.com/LizCalifaq/status/1147256153845501952?s=20) asking for help but no luck so far. The link is below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sarah, and welcome to History:SE.  I've updated the link to point to the specific tweet, rather than just to your cousin's Twitter account.  You might gate a better response though if the actual image was added to your question.

Comment: Thank you! I meant to do it that way.

Comment: I've added the picture for you. I would still highly suggest replacing that one with the original, if you still have it, as its liable to be higher-resolution, allowing zooms on details like the buttons and that hat design to be more informative.

Comment: I tried to take some close-ups of the hat and buttons, but they were all more blurry than the image above. This photo is tiny - 2'' wide and less than 3.5'' tall. I'll keep trying to get a clear close-up and post it if I do. Thanks!

Comment: @Sarah You might try a flatbed scanner -an office supply store might do this for you ar their service desk.

Comment: That is definitely a US Civil War staff officer's kepi, second hat from the left on the second row of [this image](https://www.minecreek.info/museum-philadelphia/union-officers-headgear-and-insignia.html) -- probably Union but not completely sure because the CSA had a hat like it. But there aren't any insignia on the shoulders.

Comment: The idea of a Union staff officer fits well with this [staff officer's belt](https://historical.ha.com/itm/military-and-patriotic/civil-war/a-very-rare-civil-war-union-army-staff-officer-s-silk-and-leather-belt-and-cartridge-box-this-is-a-very-rare-surviving-silk-/a/663-72177.s)

Comment: @Spencer Thank you so much for the info! This is so exciting. No one knew we had family in the Civil War. I'll have to get on Ancestry and see if I can track down any records. (Btw - I took the photo to get scanned today, but they didn't want to do it since it's metal. They were worried it might scratch the glass.)

Comment: I do not see any shoulder straps, so I suspect he is either a rated masters mate or a 3rd assistant engineer, US Navy, circa 1864.  A clear shot of his cap insignia would let us tell which, but alas.  That frock coat is navy pattern, not army and the belt buckle is indicative of a petty officer, not a commissioned officer.